# base64 is not converted image it show image may be damaged or unable to open a image

Tags: node.js

```
var http = require('http'),
url = require('url'),
fs = require('fs');
var express = require('express')
, app = module.exports = express();
 var router=express.Router();
//var fs = require('fs');
// string generated by canvas.toDataURL()
router.get('/', function(req, res, next){
var img = 
"Right_9660009901_20170707_172902_1023927555.jpg";
// strip off the data: url prefix to get just the base64-encoded bytes
var fs = require("fs");
fs.writeFile("image.jpg", new Buffer(img, "base64"), function(err) {});
 });
```

in above code the base64 is not converted to proper image and show either image has damaged or format not correct. what wrong with this code??

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to convert `img` variable into `base64` encoded buffer, not your actual image. You need to read the image file into buffer, then write to file.

e.g.

```
router.get('/', function(req, res, next){
   fs.readFile(img, { encoding: 'base64'}, function (err, data ) {
     if (err) {
        throw err;
     }

     fs.writeFile("image.jpg", data, function(err) {
        if (err) {
           throw err;
        }
        res.send("Successfully converted the image")
     });
  });
});
```